# Special Metric on the set of intervals

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $X=\{[a,b]\ a,b \in R$ and $a<b \}$ and Let $y=\{(a,b)\ a,b \in R $ and $ a<b \}$ then we define a metric on X as:

$$d( [a,b], [c,d] )= \inf \{\epsilon >0 : [a,b]\subseteq [c-\epsilon, d+\epsilon] \ \text{and} \ [c,d]\subseteq [a-\epsilon,b+\epsilon]\}.$$

Does $(X,d) $ define a metric space?

Now if we consider the canonical extension of $d$ call it $D$ on $Z:=X\bigcup Y$ is $(Z,D)$ a metric space?

Comment: What have you done so far?
**Hint (2.)** consider $$D([a_0,b_0] , (a_0,b_0))$$
What does this tell you about $D$?

Comment: I have proved that the first one is a metric space since it is basically a minimum of a set considering the cases when the 2 intervals overlap or not and for the second one D([a,b],(a,b)) would be 0. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct and what does it say about $D$ if $x\neq y$ but $D(x,y) = 0$?

Comment: It contradicts the distance definition so it is not a metric space on Z.

Comment: And voila you're done with both tasks ;-)